# how to add array of objects in react native

Tags: arrays, react-native, javascript-objects, reduce

I have an array of object:

```js
    const totalItems = [
      {
        id: 0,
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        item: 'ITEM 1',
        fat: 20,
        prt: 30,
        cho: 0,
        cal: 300,
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        item: 'ITEM 2',
        fat: 10,
        prt: 15,
        cho: 0,
        cal: 150,
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        item: 'ITEM 3',
        fat: 30,
        prt: 10,
        cho: 0,
        cal: 310,
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        item: 'ITEM 4',
        fat: 0,
        prt: 0,
        cho: 30,
        cal: 120,
      },
    ];
```

Now I want to add all the fat objects. I have used reduce() method. But it is not working. I am new at this. Kindly help me

Comment: Show your expected answer

Answer (score 1):

you can map over the array and add the fat.
something like this

```
    let totalFat = 0 ;
    totalItems.map((item) => {
    // I see there is no fat key value in first object id:0 so this check 
    // to make sure value exist
      item.fat && (totalFat = totalFat + item.fat)
    })

    console.log(totalFat)
```

In SO while asking questions please give more details like the code you have tried, it's easier to understand that way.

Comment: I tried doing this but this is showing NAN as the totalFat

Comment: The first object in your array id:0 have no fat key and value so you will have to add the check like I added in my code or else you will get NaN add check like this `item.fat && (totalFat = totalFat + item.fat)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method (forEach or map ).